# How to get the nearest marker on the polyline?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to get the nearest marker when I move the mouse over the polyline.
The markers are on the same polyline.
The markers are hidden, and I want to display the nearest to the mouse one, then the next one and to hide the prev one.
Thanks

```
    // SET PATH 
      var Path = new google.maps.Polyline({
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#993300',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 4 ,
        id: 123
      });
      Path.setMap(map);

      var path = Path.getPath();
      data.map(function(val){
        path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(+val.lat, +val.lon));
        Path.setPath(path);
      })

google.maps.event.addListener(Path, 'mousemove',function(e){
  console.log(e.latLng)
})
```

Comment: Nearest to what? Your mouse? If the markers are all on the same polyline, then they are all "nearest" to the polyline.

Comment: @Adam yes, the nearest to the mouse.

Comment: Share the relevant code from your attempt(s) and point out the part(s) that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to make sure you need to load the `geometry` library when you load your google maps JavaScript API.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry">
</script>
```

Then, when you mouse over your polyline, loop over your markers and get the distance to all of them from the mouseover point (because you don't know which one is the closest until you check them all).

Here's one way to do it:

```
//your markers in an array
var markers = [];

google.maps.event.addListener(polyline,'mouseover',function(e) {
     var closestMarker;
     markers.reduce(function(carry,marker) {
        var d = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(marker.getPosition(),e.latLng);

       if(d < carry || carry == -1) {
           closestMarker = marker;
           return d;
       }

       return carry;

    },-1);

   //your marker is now in the variable closestMarker
});
```

You can figure out how to hide and display markers very easily using the [Google Maps JavaScript API marker methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I need!